# Is it possible to "crack open" the QGIS GUI to see what coding commands are executed whilst working?

Tags: qgis, gui

I would like to see the coding that is executed when working in QGIS e.g. using the tool bars and performing tasks in the GUI. Is there a way to see what coding is going on behind the GUI?

I would like to slightly edit what some of the functions do and need to see the code executed when I use the functions.

Comment: In terms of using functions from the _Processing Toobox_, you can check the history log to see how they are executed in code (from the toolbar `Processing > History`).

Answer (score 11):

QGIS is open source, so you can always see what its doing. The source code is here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS

if you follow the instructions to build QGIS from source then you can run it with a debugger and step through the code, or add extra logging to see what is going on. You will need some knowledge of C++ and build systems (QGIS uses cmake) and you'll have to install a few dependencies to get it working.

You might be able to get what you want just by inspecting the code at github without having to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in that field but the use of **listeners** in python is also a way to check whether and when given events are triggered.That gives you the possibility to execute your own code or to log things ... that's a way to check how QGIS exactly behaves.